# Getting Error while trying to decode psbt base64 to json using bitcoinjs/bip174 library

Tags: javascript, bitcoinjs, bip174-psbt

```
const base64PSBT = 'base_64';

// Decode the base64 PSBT to a Buffer
const psbtBuffer = Buffer.from(base64PSBT, 'base64');

// Parse the PSBT
const psbt = bip174.Psbt.fromBuffer(psbtBuffer);

// Convert the PSBT to a JSON object
const psbtJSON = psbt.data;

console.log(JSON.stringify(psbtJSON, null, 2));
```

error:
const unsignedTx = txGetter(unsignedTxMaps[0].value);                      ^
TypeError: txGetter is not a function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in addition to the buffer (denoted as `psbtBuffer` in the code you provided), it is necessary to pass the `txGetter` function as a second parameter to the `fromBuffer` function. If you don't do this, javaScript considers the second parameter as `undefined` so that later calls to the given function (`const unsignedTx = txGetter(unsignedTxMaps[0].value);`) will not be possible.

The `README` says the following:

> // This will parse the PSBT, and use the function you pass to parse the Transaction part
> // the function should throw if the scriptSig section is not empty
> const psbt = Psbt.fromBuffer(somePsbtBuffer, pTxFromBuffer)